# Validate Excel File data source in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, excel, data-validation

I need to load a number of Excel files using SSIS package into a SQL Server table. I am able to successfully loop through and load my Excel files into my table I do not have any issue doing that, BUT as part of the task, I need to (validate)make sure, the files have a consistent format for all of received Excel files, things I need to check are:

- Number of columns should be the same.
- Data type for each column should be the same.
- Certain columns should not have null/empty values.

What do you suggest as the best way (simplicity and performance) to do this? Is using Script task / C# a good way? (the question is only about validating the Excel file format and columns data type)

Comment: This is not an easy task, but certainly doable in application code like C#. Specifically there are frameworks that'll automatically convert it to a DataTable, handling the data types for you. But this is more of an application layer question and not a database one so much, so you'd probably be better off asking it on [StackOverflow.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: right, So other than using a C# code in script task, what other method you can suggest to use for Excel file validation in SSIS package?

Comment: Ah I thought you were up for just doing it in the application layer as C# code. I wouldn't recommend trying to do this in the database layer or SSIS, based on complexities I've faced in the past for similar use cases. Unfortunately I don't have a better suggestion though.

Comment: Load the data into a staging(s) table first, then run a validation stored proc over the data before copying "valid" data to the final table(s)?